# tips the scales

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***tip the scales*** mean in this context?

> "It's an arms race between those coming up with the tools to counter
>   the problem and bad actors, and we want to be sure our work ***tips
>   the scales*** in favor of the good guys," said Jigsaw Product Manager
>   Santiago Andrigo in a statement. "Considering this, we are being very
>   careful and intentional about who gets access to Assembler, and very
>   diligent in monitoring for potential signs of abuse."

Source : https://www.cnet.com/news/google-parent-alphabet-takes-on-deepfakes-with-bogus-photo-detector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [tip the scales/balance](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/tip-the-balance-scales)

**If something tips the balance or tips the scales, it is the thing that causes a particular situation to happen or a particular decision to be made, when other situations or decisions are possible.**

Imagine scales where on one hand we have the bad guys and the good guys on the other. Now gently place your finger on the hand with the good guys. This way you tilt or tip the scales in the favor of the good guys.